# <?php ?> not allowing php to be rendered (xampp)

Tags: php

I have searched for this for the last few days, so if you know of a duplicate that is specific to this problem (not just a php download link) please post :)

The problem is that .php files are loading as plain text on google chrome (and blank on firefox). This problem happened when I originally started to use .php (i thought it came with the browser like html). I since then have downloaded xampp and have been fiddling with the program to get it to finally work (using ports 8080 and 4433 if you are familiar with that solution).

Then, after finally getting it to work and starting a php tutorial, the php code suddenly stopped working and was again presented as plaintext. I am currently running the code:

```
<?php echo 'Hi world'; ?>
```

and that's it. (Yes, i have tried removing the last tag).

If it helps come to a solution, when i enter localhost I need to type in http://localhost:8080 to get to the xampp dashboard.

When i run a .php file with just html code, it works fine.

Please help and/or explain all of this to me so I don't encounter errors every 2 seconds like a newcomer to any language is wont to do.

Comment: You have to use localhost in order render PHP files,you can't use file:/// and expect to use php at same time!

Comment: what URL are you using to access the script?

Comment: How do I use localhost to render php files? The files are saved in C:/xampp/mysql/data/tutorialfolder/index.php

Comment: PHP files are interpreted by your server, you should put them in your apache document root folder. Often "xampp/htdocs" .

Comment: It's still not working @deg
PS here is the tutorial I am referencing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xb8aad4MRx8  (go to 29:30)
he is loading it from localhost/loginsystem (where loginsystem is the name of the tutorial folder).
I am trying localhost:8080/loginsystem and localhost/loginsystem:8080 but they do not work. (localhost/loginsystem doesnt either)

Comment: Assuming you already have a index.html file in /htdocs, replace it with one of your making, and then hit http://localhost and confirm that it leads to your own freshly just made index.html. If there is an index.php same thing, you are trying to make sure you are debugging in the correct spot.

Comment: lets assume you moved your `tutorialfolder/index.php` to `xampp/htdocs` then your localhost URL should be `http://localhost:8080/tutorialfolder/index.php`

Comment: Also make sure you start Apache services from XAMPP

Comment: What Kumaran says, too. I just took the worst for granted and went for checking that the default docroot is the one in use. Which you can also check by moving the folder and trying to access the suggested url.

Comment: @MuthuKumaran thank you, this worked. I think the problem was that the htdocs needed its own folder and I was trying to use the database folder. Thank you ! Make your comment an answer and i'll mark it

Comment: No, no, the problem is you were trying to run php from outside apache. Imagine The Server starts in /htdocs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you moved your `tutorialfolder/index.php` to `xampp/htdocs` then your localhost URL should be `http://localhost:8080/tutorialfolder/index.php`

Also make sure you start Apache services from XAMPP